# how to run the selenium with python script for login using command line

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

here is my code

```
def test_login(self):
        URL = (sys.argv[0])
        Username = (sys.argv[1])
        Password = (sys.argv[2])
        self.driver.get(URL)
        print ("Browser launched")
        self.driver.find_element(By.NAME, "username").send_keys(Username)
        self.driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "btn-login-submit").click()
        time.sleep(7)  
        self.driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password").send_keys(Password)
        self.driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "btn-login-submit").click()
        time.sleep(10)
        print('login successful')
```

**how to run in the vscode terminal**
i could not get the proper command line to run in terminal

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Copy Paste the code in a .py file say `test.py`
- I do not see the calling of the function (test_login). So call it or remove the function if it is not necessary.
- in the VS code terminal, type this command `Python3 test.py` to execute your python script.